# Define a subroutine that can be called via method syntax

Tags: raku

`sqrt` can be called via function syntax:

```
> sqrt 16
4
```

It can also be called via method syntax:

```
> 16.sqrt
4
```

Is there a way to make user defined subroutines invokable via method syntax?

For example, let's define `sq`:

```
> sub sq(Int $n) { $n*$n }
sub sq (Int $n) { #`(Sub|64042864) ... }
> sq 4
16
```

Is there a way to make it callable as a method? I.e.

```
> 4.sq
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way to make user defined subroutines invokable via method syntax?

Yes, just use the `.&` syntax, as in:

```
625.&sqrt.say
# 25
```

The invocant is passed as the first argument:

```
sub sq { $^a² }; say 4.&sq
4.&sq.say
# 16
```

The only catch is you have to use unspace if you want to break up the method chain with these onto multiple lines:

```
4.&sq\
 .&sq.say;
```

Comment: Thank  you Zoffix!

Answer (score 5):

You can use monkey-typing to augment `Int`. Expect the optimiser to bail, your willy/boobs to shrink and the world to end in general. Monkey-typing is evil. Don't use it unless you have to.

```
use MONKEY-TYPING; 
augment class Int { method sq(Int:D $i:){ $i * $i } };
my Int $i = 4;
say $i.sq;
```

You can mixin a role to the object. Note that the object is the object, not the class `Int` nor the container `$i`.

```
my $i = 4 but role :: { method sq(Int:D $i:){ $i * $i } };
say $i.sq;
```

You can create a free floating method and use `.&` method call operator.

```
my method sq(Int:D $i:){ $i * $i };
my $i = 4;
say $i.&sq;
```

EDIT:

If you really want to break assumptions you can even access private attributes.

```
class Foo { has $!bar = 'meow'; };
use MONKEY-TYPING;
augment class Foo { method baz { say $!bar } };
Foo.new.baz
# OUTPUT«meow␤»
```

Comment: Thanks gfldex! I'm surprised to see that this doesn't seem to be well supported.

Comment: @dharmatech if it feels not well supported then your solution may not fit to the problem you have. Unless you provide details why you want to add a method from the outside to a class nobody can give you good advice. Perl 6 is using precompiled modules. If you augment a class that is used by such a module the compiler may have to recompile that module, triggering a rather long chain of slowness. Perl 6 is meant to provide a compiler with enough rope to nit fast bytecode. That comes at a price.

Comment: I would like add that the `augment class`-example allows access to private attributes of that class, while all other examples do not.

Comment: To explain why this is "evil": your augment affects the entire program, even modules loaded before your augment will see the new method you add.